# Get youtube video current time

Tags: javascript, html, youtube, youtube-api

I am trying to get youtube video current time.I cant find solution.could any ne help me in this my code i am trying which works for ordinary videos is

```
<button onClick="getCurTime()" type="button">Get current time position</button>
<button onClick="setCurTime()" type="button">Set time position to 5 seconds</button>
<br>
<embed width="420" height="315" id="myVideo"
            src="http://www.youtube.com/v/XGSy3_Czz8k"> 
<script>
var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo");

function getCurTime() {
    alert(vid.currentTime);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Hi @king refer this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/P54jV/

Answer (score 0):

```
<embed width="420" height="315" id="myVideo"
        src="http://www.youtube.com/v/XGSy3_Czz8k">



    <script>
        var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo");

        function getCurTime() {
            alert(vid.getCurrentTime());
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/hnkK7/ Please check this link I think it's related to your problem.